# Kannel 1.4.3 Huawei e220 initialization error Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sms, usb-modem

I am new to Kannel. Trying to setup SMS send/receive using Kannel 1.4.3 with Huawei e220 modem. OS: Ubuntu 14.04 lts.

I am getting this error in bearerbox:

```
2014-10-15 20:55:50 [3425] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei-E220-00]: --> AT+CSCA="my number"
2014-10-15 20:55:51 [3425] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei-E220-00]: <-- ERROR
2014-10-15 20:55:51 [3425] [6] ERROR: AT2[Huawei-E220-00]: Generic error: ERROR
2014-10-15 20:55:51 [3425] [6] ERROR: AT2[Huawei-E220-00]: Initialization of device failed.
2014-10-15 20:55:51 [3425] [6] INFO: AT2[Huawei-E220-00]: Closing device
2014-10-15 20:55:51 [3425] [6] ERROR: AT2[Huawei-E220-00]: Couldn't connect (retrying in 10 seconds).
```

Unable to reset CSCA from minicom AT commands also, it gives ERROR.

Here is my smskannel.conf setting:

```
#---------------------------------------------
# CORE
#

group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = bar
#status-password = foo 
#admin-deny-ip = ""
#admin-allow-ip = ""
log-file = "/tmp/kannel.log"
log-level = 0
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"
#unified-prefix = "+358,00358,0;+,00"
#access-log = "/tmp/access.log"
#store-file = "kannel.store"
#ssl-server-cert-file = "cert.pem"
#ssl-server-key-file = "key.pem" 
#ssl-certkey-file = "mycertandprivkeyfile.pem"

#---------------------------------------------
# SMSC CONNECTIONS
#

group = smsc
smsc = at
smsc-id = Huawei-E220-00
port = 10000
modemtype = huawei_e220_00
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
sms-center = "my number"
my-number = "my number"
connect-allow-ip = 127.0.0.1
sim-buffering = true
keepalive = 5
log-level = 0

#---------------------------------------------
# SMSBOX SETUP
#

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = "my number"
#sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
#log-file = "/tmp/smsbox.log"
log-level = 0
#access-log = "/tmp/access.log"

#---------------------------------------------
# SEND-SMS USERS
#

group = sendsms-user
username = tester
password = foobar
#user-deny-ip = ""
#user-allow-ip = ""
concatenation= true
max-messages = 10

#---------------------------------------------
# SERVICES
#

group = sms-service
keyword = default
catch-all = yes
max-messages = 0
#get-url = "http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&    to=number&text=Hello"
get-url = http://localhost/sms?phone=%p&text=%a

#---------------------------------------------
# MODEMS
#
group = modems
id = huawei_e220_00
name = "Huawei E220"
detect-string = "huawei"
init-string = "ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0"
message-storage = "SM"
need-sleep = true
speed = 9600
```

Comment: Can some one help please?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with Kannel.
Were you using your USB-modem to connect internet while you try to start Kannel?
If so, disconnect internet connection and try.

USB ports working properly? Sometimes, some USB-modems are giving problems with Kannel. So try with an another model. I am using Huawei E173 for Kannel. Its working properly.